# Why does my Arduino keep uploading?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am having some trouble uploading my Arduino code. I recently fixed my old Macbook Pro, and installed Arduino on it. The problem is that the IDE is infinitely uploading the program when I press upload. There are no error messages. I don't really know what to do next.

I looked all over Stack Overflow but didn't find the answer to my question. Maybe one of you can help me. It would mean a lot to me.

Sometimes it doesn't even upload, it compiles and gives a error message

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/cu.usbmodem1d11": Resource busy
>   ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
>
> Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Have you enabled verbose mode (compilation and uploading)?

Comment: I just did that, it didn't work. It's a Macbook Pro 2007, not a unibody. I'm running OS X El Capitan on it. Maybe the latest Arduino IDE is not compatible with my mac?

Comment: So, after enabling verbose mode you don't see any error messages? Does it display any info at all? You can enlarge the black area at the bottom to see messages displayed upon compilation and uploading.